# guild.members.fetch(); throws a error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'members') not sure why?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Im making a discord bot and im trying to get the names/id's of everyone in a server using guild.members.fetch();

However no matter what I've tried it always sends the error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'members')

Heres the code im using.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS] });
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("Server_ID");
async function fetchmembs() {
    const members = await guild.members.fetch();
    return members;
}
members = fetchmembs();
console.log(members);
```

It always throws this Error:

```
const members = await guild.members.fetch();                                  
                            ^ 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'members')
```

I've tried almost everything I've found online to no help. I'm relatively new to coding and discord bot making so I'm not sure.
I have guild Members intents enabled, put it in a async function, with a await and the start.

This is my first question so sorry if I've left stuff out or done stuff wrong
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `guild` declaration in the function. By the time the function is called, the client should be ready and the guilds would be cached

```js
async function fetchmembs() {
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("Server_ID");
    const members = await guild.members.fetch();
    return members;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, That works, still returns members as a promise but I should be able to deal with that i hope. Thanks!

Comment: @Tetrakai the function must return the promise because it's asynchronous and does asynchronous actions

Answer (score 0):

There is no guild in your bot's cache. You need to fetch it instead of getting it from guilds cache:

```js
const guild = await client.guilds.fetch('Guild_ID');
```

remember to put this in an async module or `await` won't be available

Comment: I've done this however now it is saying that .fetch() is undefined. ive done a bit of extra research and debugging and found that guild.members is undefined. although im not sure how im suppost to define it.

Comment: exactly the `guild` is undefined. You are trying to get the guild from bot's cache but there is no guild in.

Comment: I've used 'client.guilds.fetch('Guild_ID');' like you said instead of getting it from the cache. console.log(guild) just returns a promise <pending>

Comment: `guild` should be `await client.guilds.fetch('Guild_ID')` because `fetch()` return a promise result

Comment: i am using await client.guilds.fetch('Guild_ID') to get the guild. but it still returns a promise result